# passing a dataframe to a thread

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-multithreading

Inside a function, I created a local dataframe with name resamp_df. I am trying to pass this local dataframe to a thread function as an argument for running some algorithm on it. Here is my code:

main function

```
if readyForOrder:
    order_thread = threading.Thread(target=order_management, name='thread1', args=resamp_df)
    order_thread.start()
```

thread function

```
def order_management(df):
    global  readyForOrder, order_id, order_id_counter, ltp
    if df.shape[0] >= 3:
         readyForOrder = False
         old_ltp = df.iat[-2, 0]
         new_ltp = df.iat[-1, 0]
```

But my thread is not running. It generates following errors:

```
TypeError: order_management() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given
```

Any suggestions to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `args=(saving_df, )` @KawaiKx

Comment: You may want to fix the indentation in the question, so that it is clearer

Comment: @Vishnudev now it triggers this warning 
builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resamp_df' referenced before assignment

Comment: We need to see the declaration/definition of the variable `resamp_df`

Comment: I solved the unboundlocalerror myself.. your initial comment helped.. if you write it as answer, I will choose it. @Vishnudev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in arguments as a tuple

```
args=(resamp_df, )
```

as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) mentions args as a tuple.

Args is a tuple because the task function takes multiple positional arguments and you need to have an appropriate data structure to hold that.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this :)